# Can Facebook Connect app pre-segment users?

Tags: facebook, facebook-insights, segment

Does anyone know if Facebook Connect can be set up where the pass variable can be set up so users can be segmented into different groups in advance so that insights from the app can be pulled in a way that also reflects those segmentations?

It's essentially similar to running multiple apps off of a single app ID.

If not, does anyone know if app IDs can be dynamically created? I know as of a couple years ago, this wasn't possible, but was curious if anyone knows if this has changed in recent time.

As an aside, we have a self service platform and are looking for a way to automate, but also to segment the Facebook connect insights data. So if anyone has any other ideas, have done it on the software side, or know of any plugins that may to help, that'd be really helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean segment the data? There used to be a way to create apps dynamically, but it got pulled (probably from abuse). Also, directly some users to one app and others to another app based on characteristics of the user will lead to poor facebook integration and distribution and your app will suffer as a result of it

Comment: Thanks, Tommy. I was hoping there was a way to assign categories in advance that fans could be associated to. We work with multiple merchants and fans come through our app in relation to those merchants. We were hoping that was a way to pre-assign them to that merchant in advance to avoid the need to create a new app ID for every merchant so we can pull the relevant analytics for them. Thanks again!

Comment: Nope, there is no way to associate a tag with a user for analytic purposes. Your best bet to use another Analytics service for your own tracking.

Comment: Thanks, Tommy. I appreciate you getting back to me so quickly.